# Запилить XNA библиотеки в проект

Tags: c#, xna

Каким образом можно скомпилировать XNA приложение так, чтобы оно запускалось на любом компе без предварительной установки XNA Game Studio и .NET Framework 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если коротко — никак. Только XNA Game Studio не требуется, достаточно более компактного XNA Framework Redistributable.

Однако можно почти без усилий портировать XNA на MonoGame, что снизит зависимости до просто .NET Framework 4.